# symfony 4.2 behat tests memory leak

Tags: symfony, symfony4, behat

After upgrading from `Symfony` 4.1 to `Symfony` 4.2 Behat tests started to eat a lots of memory. Before upgrade `5k` tests used about `~200` Mb of memory, after upgrading process fails on `~2Gb` memory limit. How to understand where the problem is?

Comment: Hard to say. But it may me a regression or bug of the 4.2 version as it is still young. Try looking on the Github bug tracker:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=behat and create an issue. It is more likely the problem comes from Symfony rather than Behat.

Comment: Which parts are affected? Behat uses some kind of browser process, so it would be interesting to know whether the Behat process itself uses more memory, or your webserver serving the tested pages

Comment: We use console application for testing API (behat/symfony2-extension) without browsers.

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29643

Comment: Do you use the ext-intl package by any chance?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend yes

Comment: We had the same issue and it was because of this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31089

Comment: We had to upgrade to 4.3